# Reset timer each iteration of a loop

Tags: c++, timer

My intention is to create a program which analyzes different numbers of samples and every sample has a time limit. So the timer must reset for every sample. As well, must be a while loop which makes sure the program doesn't run for too long.

Code:

```
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <ctime>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <unistd.h>

 //All functions declaration


 int main(){
//function which read all the sample to analyse

for (int sample=0;sample<numOfSamples;sample++){

 srand(time(NULL));

float tMax = tMax();//A function which calculates the maxium time for that sample

clock_t t;
t=clock();

//Some more functions which are not important

time= (clock()-t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

   while(time<tMax){

   //Do different functions

    time=(clock()-t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   cout<<"Timer: "<<time<<endl;

   }//End of while
}//End of For Loop (Samples)
}//ENd of main
```

That's my code, as you see there is no reset on my timer yet because I have no idea how to use it. But the main problem it's the timer time, it's always 0. So it's always lower than tMax.

How can I reset the timer and get a value greater than 0?

Comment: Wy do you need to reset the timer? Just measure the time and use time differences. BTW on which system are you running that? If on Linux, read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Comment: C++11 has [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) standard header

Answer (score 3):

As Basile said, you can use `<chrono>`:

```
// create chrono start time
auto startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

//Some more functions which are not important

// get elapsed time
auto elapsedTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = elapsedTime - _startTime;

// check if duration expires
auto numSeconds = elapsed_seconds.count();
while (numSeconds < tMax)
{
    // Do different functions

    // check again
    elapsedTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    elapsed_seconds = elapsedTime - _startTime;
    numSeconds = elapsed_seconds.count();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I'm going to try it!

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your computer is fast enough so that the measured time is always much less than one second and rounded to zero.

<sup>When benchmarking, it is better to ensure that your computation is taking more than half a second, perhaps by repeating that computation many times.</sup>

If on Linux, read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). Consider using [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) with C++11 (i.e. compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g -O`)

You could convert the result of `clock()` to a double floating point:

```
clock_t starttime= clock();
do_some_long_computation();
clock_t endtime= clock();
cout << "long computation took: " 
     << ((double)(endtime-starttime)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC) 
     << endl;
```

Comment: I doubt this link will die any time soon.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast